# How to enter \ character in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, secret-management

I have

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "mcasz2" {
  name = "mcasz/client/credentials"
  description = "mcasz 2.0 secretes for back-end"
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "mcasz2Credentials" {
  secret_id     = "${aws_secretsmanager_secret.mcasz2.id}"
  secret_string = "{\"/secrets/dev/jdbc-url2\":\"jdbc:postgresql://mcasz20database-instance-1.c6r2nfvt8woo.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5499/mcasz_masterdata_dev\",\"/secrets/dev/username3\":\"mcasz_db_admin\",\"/secrets/dev/password2\":\"s8maLeZ4Tnyw\",\"/secrets/dev/okta_issuer\":\"https://trial-5044821.okta.com/oauth2/default\",\"/secrets/dev/okta_client_id\":\"0oaam5aqz1g0DQlrp617\",\"/secrets/dev/okta_client_secret\":\"c9y4iVNneV3CzjS4KpWUOJ3pfTA8EX9H5FUHIpi0PTzGQPhdYOuz6Tiypm174hpa\",\"/secrets/dev/jdbc-url-supply\":\"jdbc:postgresql://mcasz20database-instance-1.c6r9nfvt7woo.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/mcasz_suppy_dev\",,\"/secrets/dev/jdbc-url-tranation\":\"jdbc:postgresql://mcasz20database-instance-2.c9r9nfvt7woo.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5488/mcasz_trans_dev\"}"
}
```

Created secret manager success, but get value error.
Please help me enter `\` in correct way, for example

```
/secrets/dev/jdbc-url2
```